# Question with ODE's without constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am an assistant professor of ordinary differential equations at my university, but focused on engineering. The course is simpler and was the one I gave myself in the past. The professor who coordinates those of us who are assistant professors asked to do the following differential equation and here is my development, but it is a content that I do not remember seeing in the course.
\begin{gather*}
x^2 y'' -x(x+2) y' + (x+2) y = 2x^3   \\
\end{gather*}
First, we always solve the homogeneous
\begin{gather}
x^2 y'' - x (x+2) y'+ (x+2) y = 0 \\
\end{gather}
In which, I will divide a term to then carry out a substitution respecting the following
\begin{gather}
y'' + y' \frac{(-x-2)}{x} + y\frac{x+2}{x^2} =0 \\
y''+y' f(x) + y g(x) =0 \\
y= e^{-\int f(x)/2 dx } \cdot v 
\end{gather}
Then, making the respective substitutions and simplifying a bit, we have that
\begin{equation}
e^{\frac{x}{2}} x v'' - \frac{1}{4} e^{\frac{x}{2}} xv = 0
\end{equation}
Dividing and then using the characteristic polynomial, we have
\begin{equation}
v= c_1 e^{\frac{-x}{2}} + c_2 e^{\frac{x}{2}}
\end{equation}
restoring the terms for "$y$"
\begin{equation}
y= c_1 x + c_2 e^x x 
\end{equation}
Then I solve the particular using variation of parameters, which is a method that I am quite familiar with
\begin{gather}
y_p= -2x^2 -2x \\
y= y_p + y_h = c_1 x+ c_2 x e^x -2(x^2 +x)
\end{gather}
Is my procedure correct?

**Edit**: I checked my result by substituting the solutions in the expression, and it seems to be fine

Comment: When you divided through by $x^2$, you only divided the coefficient of $y$ by $x$ (but maybe that was a typo, and you used the correct value later on). I never knew there was such a thing as "an assistant professor of ordinary differential equations".

Comment: @GerryMyerson it 's a typo. In my country we have "ayudantes", it's an assistant professor and we do another class solving question, problems, when they have exams, we are who correct their tests

Answer (score 1):

You can combine terms as
$$
x^2x''-(x+2)(xy'-y)=2x^3.
$$
From this it can be seen that $y=x$ is a basis solution of the homogeneous equation. The equation should thus simplify when trying to find the solution in the form $y=xu$,
$$
x^2[xu''+2u']-(x+2)[x^2u']=2x^3\\
u''-u'=2\\
(u'+2)'=u'+2\\
u'+2=ce^x\\
u=-2x+ce^x+d\\
y=-2x^2+cxe^x+dx
$$
This is indeed the same solution if you combine in yours the two terms containing $x$ into one.